# Navigation not displayed when resizing the browser in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for navigation and it's not displaying the 3 horizontal bars that must be displayed when resizing the browser.

Below is my code:

```html
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" TYPE="text/css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-invesre">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Team Management</a>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a>Teams List</a>
        </li>
        <li><a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add Team</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As shown in the code, icon bar should be displayed when resizing the browser, but it's not. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have jquery and Bootstrap JS loading along with your Bootstrap CSS? (And per the Docs navbar-brand is placed after the closing button tag inside the navbar-header.)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but jQuery and bootstrap.js are required for the functionality. I am not still able to see the icon bar, I haven't yet tried to click it.. Changing the navbar-brand didn't make any effect

Comment: You have inverse spelled incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

As @vanburenx pointed out you simply spelled inverse incorrectly. The hamburger menu, as it's called, is there its just white on white. Change to :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
```